# How to know which code fragement is responsible for displaying an image in a Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-inspector

When I inspect an image on any website, I can see the html tag <img and the src="..".

For Wordpress sites, which uses hundreds of includes and requires, however, is very hard to tell which line in code exactly displays the image. Is there an easy way to tell this?

Comment: Right click on the image and press inspect. There should either be an img tag or a background-image/background css property with the path to the image. This is not a wordpress or php issue.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: @merlinfejzuli: you can indeed see the path to the image, but not the code that is responsible for that, and I have to change the code. And it is usually a php line that does that,